# CSS+JS modal with fadeout

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog

I'm having a go at creating a modal, tbh the code is not mine but I tried modifying it to have a fadeout closing effect.

I created the animation of fadeout but the way I'm hiding the modal is with js `setTimeout` after the close animation is finished which I know is not the right way to go.

```js
// Get the modal
    let modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    let modalContent = document.querySelector(".modal-content");

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    let btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function () {
        modalContent.classList.add('modal-content');
        modalContent.classList.remove('modal-content-close');
        modal.style.display = "block";
    };

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function () {

        modalContent.classList.add('modal-content-close');
        modalContent.classList.remove('modal-content');
        setTimeout(() => modal.style.display = "none", 300)
    };

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modalContent.classList.add('modal-content-close');
            modalContent.classList.remove('modal-content');
            setTimeout(() => modal.style.display = "none", 300)
        }
    }
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
        .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 20px; /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 0;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 30%;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
            animation-name: animatetop;
            animation-duration: 0.4s
        }

        .modal-content-close {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 0;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 30%;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            -webkit-animation-name: animatetopclose;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
            animation-name: animatetopclose;
            animation-duration: 0.4s
        }

        /* Add Animation - Open */
        @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
            from {
                top: -300px;
                opacity: 0
            }
            to {
                top: 0;
                opacity: 1
            }
        }

        @keyframes animatetop {
            from {
                top: -300px;
                opacity: 0
            }
            to {
                top: 0;
                opacity: 1
            }
        }

        /* Add Animation - Close */
        @-webkit-keyframes animatetopclose {
            from {
                top: 0;
                opacity: 1
            }
            to {
                top: -300px;
                opacity: 0
            }
        }

        @keyframes animatetopclose {
            from {
                top: 0;
                opacity: 1
            }
            to {
                top: -300px;
                opacity: 0
            }
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            color: white;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .modal-header {
            padding: 2px 16px;
            background-color: #5cb85c;
            color: white;
        }

        .modal-body {
            padding: 2px 16px;
        }

        .modal-footer {
            padding: 2px 16px;
            background-color: #5cb85c;
            color: white;
        }
```

```html
<h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <h2>Modal Header</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
            <p>Some other text...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

What IS the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you think that? I don't find any problem in the code.

Comment: @Tavish Aggarwal I'm looking for a way I wouldn't need js for the hide effect, mostly css if that's possible.

Comment: Have you considered using a transition with some delay? Like e.g. `transition: opacity .4s ease .3s;` (.3s being the delay)?